# Find start date and end date from the employee time clock

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find out star date and end date for the employee time clock. Following is the example of the data I have.

```
PersonID  EventTime                       ActivityCode
1         2019-07-29 00:03:03.000         7
1         2019-07-29 00:09:41.000         0
1         2019-07-29 00:01:07.000         7
1         2019-07-29 00:01:19.000         0
```

Output wanted:

```
PersonID  EventTime                   EndTime                           ActivityCode
1         2019-07-29 00:03:03.000     2019-07-29 00:09:41.000            7
1         2019-07-29 00:09:41.000     2019-07-29 00:01:07.000            0
1         2019-07-29 00:01:07.000      2019-07-29 00:01:19.000           7
1         2019-07-29 00:01:19.000                                        0
```

I have to find the start date and end date of the person based on eventtime and activitycode. The start date will be event time column and I have to calculate end date from the same column which is next eventtime in the row.

I've tried using lead function in T-SQL but it's not giving me the result I want.

```
select personid, activitycode, eventtime as starttime
    , (lead(eventtime) over (order by personid)) as endtime 
from ActivityTable
```

If anyone has some idea how to deal with this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you explain your order  I don't see how 3:03 on 7/29 comes before 1:07...  I think you just need to `order by personID, EventTime` (maybe descending)  but i'm not sure how you're getting the order in your desired results..... on the window function... [RexTester Example](https://rextester.com/RNX72796)  built to save others time

Comment: If order doesn't matter then your lead time function should work.  The output you want is slightly misleading since you have a EventTime that happens after a EndTime.

Comment: Why do you start with 2019-07-20 00:03:03 when 00:01:07 appears to be the first entry of the day?

Comment: The event time depends on the activitycode. Example: endtime for one activitycode will be the next eventtime in the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your EventTime should be 13:00 rather than 01:00

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([PersonID] varchar(50),[EventTime] datetime,[ActivityCode] int)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'2019-07-29 00:03:03.000',7)
,(1,'2019-07-29 00:09:41.000',0)
,(1,'2019-07-29 00:13:07.000',7)  << changed to 13
,(1,'2019-07-29 00:13:19.000',0)  << changed to 13

Select PersonID
      ,EventTime 
      ,EndTime= lead([EventTime],1) over (partition by [PersonID] order by [EventTime])
      ,ActivityCode
 From @YourTable
 Order by EventTime
```

**Returns**

```
PersonID    EventTime                 EndTime                   ActivityCode
1           2019-07-29 00:03:03.000   2019-07-29 00:09:41.000   7
1           2019-07-29 00:09:41.000   2019-07-29 00:13:07.000   0
1           2019-07-29 00:13:07.000   2019-07-29 00:13:19.000   7
1           2019-07-29 00:13:19.000   NULL                      0
```

Comment: Wow... why didn't I think of that...  stupid AM/PM :P

Comment: This is great..Thanks John.

Comment: @droptable007 Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Your output looks kind of weird in your example since your EventTime an seem to happen after your EndTime.  If you are looking for a ordering of time and are expecting a result set like this:

[image]

Then xQbert's comment is correct.  You only need to add EventTime in your Order By.  See example code below.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (
    PersonID INT
    ,EventTime DATETIME
    ,ActivityCode INT
)

INSERT INTO #T(
    PersonID
    ,EventTime
    ,ActivityCode
)
SELECT
    PersonID
    ,EventTime
    ,ActivityCode
FROM
    (VALUES ( 1,'2019-07-29 00:03:03.000', 7)
            ,(1,'2019-07-29 00:09:41.000', 0)
            ,(1,'2019-07-29 00:01:07.000', 7)
            ,(1,'2019-07-29 00:01:19.000', 0)) AS T (PersonID,EventTime,ActivityCode)


SELECT
    PersonID
    ,ActivityCode
    ,EventTime AS starttime
    ,(LEAD(EventTime) OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, EventTime DESC)) AS endtime
FROM
    #T;
```

Comment: Please note: The above code ignores ActivityCode.  Maybe you want to go off of that as it might represent check-in and checking-out?  If that's the case, the above code allows a situation where "double" check-in or check-out could return corrupt data for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try Like This..

```
  CREATE TABLE #T 
 (
PersonID INT
,EventTime DATETIME
,ActivityCode INT
)



INSERT INTO #T(
PersonID
,EventTime
,ActivityCode
)
SELECT
PersonID
,EventTime
,ActivityCode
FROM
(VALUES ( 1,'2019-07-29 00:03:03.000', 7)
        ,(1,'2019-07-29 00:09:41.000', 0)
        ,(1,'2019-07-29 00:13:07.000', 7)
        ,(1,'2019-07-29 00:13:19.000', 0)) AS T (PersonID,EventTime,ActivityCode)

SELECT  PersonID,EventTime,ActivityCode,
    (SELECT MIN(EventTime) FROM #T T2 WHERE T1.PersonID = T2.PersonID AND 
    T1.EventTime < T2.EventTime)
  FROM  #T T1
```